# Live Streaming- HLS + RTSP using Video.js (Wowza Server)

Tags: rtsp, video.js, live-streaming, wowza, http-live-streaming

I am using a Wowza's Gocoder application to live stream video from my iPhone to the Wowza server(version 4.0.4). From the server I was able to fetch the video to my Webpage as well. I used Video.js player to do the same. But all this works only for IOS (HLS stream). Now, I would like to know if I could support streaming from my Android mobile (RTSP) as well using the same player. 
Is there something I could include to make the single player connect to the RTSP or HLS stream respectively?

Thank you for the help ! :)

*Code*:

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 document.createElement('video');document.createElement('audio');document.createElement('track');
</script>
<link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.8/video.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls preload="auto" width="500" height="300"
  poster="nfllogo.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src="http://a.b.c.d:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8" type='video/mp4'/>
  
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show RTMP streams, afaik you need to fall back to a Flash based player, but that limits your platform ad well. I googled around, but it's not clear to me if Video.js can do that. JW Player can.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yse I am trying to get the stream from an android mobile via either HLS or RTSP using video.js. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: @TelecomCoder did you found a solution for rtsp on android mobile? Does support videojs rtsp mp4 stream?